How to setup Thymeleaf for a web application?
Im developing a web app using eclipse and I want to use Thymeleaf, in particular I want to set from a servlet some variable to use then in an HTML file.
What I have to download to run the Thymeleaf engine and how I have to setup the application to make it works?

Hi there! See here for how to ask a good question on StackOverflow. What did you try?

in bootstrap you need to add a dependincy
and add the thymleaf code in the resources --> static folder
i hope i helped
